# How can I optimise the speed of my SQL query

Tags: mysql

I understand the main problem in this query is the two embedded subqueries, this will be running 2 extra queries per row returned, drastically increasing the execution complexity over a large result set.   This query was fine, but now we are approaching 2,000 users its performance is drastically declining, I have cut out as much irrelevant information as possible (mainly select fields).

```
    SELECT
             e.Entity_Id,
             f.Category AS FC,
             s.list_visibility,
             p.Pref_Everyone
      FROM
             entity e
      LEFT JOIN
             setting s
      ON
             e.Entity_Id IN(s.Entity_Id)
       AND   (s.list_visibility = 1 OR s.list_visibility = NULL)
      LEFT JOIN
             preferences p
      ON
             e.Entity_Id IN(p.Entity_Id)
       AND   (p.Pref_Everyone = 1 OR p.Pref_Everyone = NULL)
      LEFT
      JOIN
             friends f
      ON
             e.Entity_Id
      IN    (f.Entity_Id1, f.Entity_Id2)

      -- Filter out existing friends
      AND    f.Category NOT IN (1, 2, 4)  
      WHERE e.Entity_Id != :user_id
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, e.DOB, CURDATE()) BETWEEN :lower AND :upper

        -- First subquery to filter out people a friend request has been sent to
        AND e.Entity_Id NOT IN
        (
            SELECT Req_Receiver FROM friend_requests WHERE Req_Sender = :user_id

            UNION ALL

            SELECT Req_Receiver FROM friend_requests WHERE Req_Sender = e.Entity_Id AND Req_Receiver = :user_id
        )

        -- Second subquery to filter out existing friends 
        -- (only check one way as I have added a reciprocal relationship
        AND e.Entity_Id NOT IN
        (
            SELECT Entity_Id1 FROM friends WHERE Entity_Id2 = :user_id
        )

        -- Only get users within a 500km radius
        AND (6371 * acos( cos( radians(:currLat) ) * cos( radians(e.Last_CheckIn_Lat) ) * cos( radians(e.Last_CheckIn_Long) - radians(:currLong) ) + sin( radians(:currLat) ) * sin( radians(e.Last_CheckIn_Lat) ) ) ) < 500
        GROUP BY e.Entity_Id
        LIMIT 50
```

Any optimisation tips would be greatly appreciated. I don't just want an "here is the fix answer" as I'd like to be able to make these optimisations by myself in the future, an explanation as to why its faster and how the solution was arrived would be more beneficial to me.

Comment: Please post https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html, and a schema; a SQL fiddle would be amazing.

Comment: Instead of doing a subquery, just do 2 outer joins instead. Or perhaps better for MySQL, just a few separate queries. MySQL is notoriously bad at optimizing subqueries

Comment: Thanks @Wolph I'll give the outer join approach a try as I'd rather keep the logic in one query if I possibly can